# Can't add Support Library for app with min = targetSdkVersion = 10

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-support-library

I'm trying to add Android Support Library (`appcompat`) to empty project which assigned only to use with API level 10.

So, I create Android Studio project with the following options.

[image]

Then I add Support Library in the dependencies region.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 10
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 10
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
```

Then I get the following compile errors

```
MyAppProject/MyApp/build/exploded-bundles/ComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71800.aar/res/values-v14/values.xml
    Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Holo.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
    Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Holo.SearchResult.Title'.
    Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
    ...

MyAppProject/MyApp/build/exploded-bundles/ComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71800.aar/res/values-v11/values.xml
    Gradle: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
    Gradle: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
...
```

Comment: Try to change Target SDK and Compile with to 4.3 (API level 18)

Comment: @lassana, yes, this is working. But why I can't do the same for API level 10?

Comment: What the problem? Your app must work on 2.3 if minSDKVersion = 10. You should set targetSDk max value always.

Comment: @lassana, it's not a problem in practice. But I want to understand the reason why `gradle` generate files which is invalid for specified target version.

Answer (score 1):

You get error because you use resources from Android 3.0+ in your project: `'android:Theme.Holo'`.

Just set targetSDKVersion >11.
[image]

[Undersanding min/targetSdkVersion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: Does it mean that it's bug in `gradle` which makes impossible to build project if I want to restrict usage of my app with maxSdkVersion = 10?